# what is the name of this form of a circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

What is the name of this form of circle? I just forgot.

I want something to google about making circles like this but forgot about the circle form.

Comment: Um, pie? At least piecharts look exactly like that

Comment: @DarkCthulhu Ahahahahaha

Comment: no, some area is stripped

Comment: @DarkCthulhu Was about to write the same. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a *circular sector*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector)

Comment: Thanks this is what I want to know

Answer (score 1):

This form of circle is called as Sector.